# publish vs 2017 project without Azure or continuous delivery

Tags: visual-studio-2017, publish

To deploy and publish a website in visual studio I get a message telling "the solution needs to be under source control on VSTS or GitHub".

what if I ignore this kind of publishing and publish it as before versions of VS and how can I ignore it?

Comment: What was your publishing target?

Comment: "folder" or "IIS, FTP, etc"

Answer (score 3):

Chick the publish Button next to Profile and not the Start button. They are 2 different publish options.

[image]